# How to setup Code Review in free version of gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gerrit, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I want to have code review set up in my local gitlab environment.

1. Does gitlab free version provide its inbuilt review system?
2. If not then should we use Gerrit or any other free code review tool to integrate with GitLab?

Can I please get the steps to set up this environment.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab's code review is conducted via 'Merge Requests'. It's a bit of a different thing than Gerrit reviews and is more like GitHub Pull Requests, etc. See [Merge Request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/) documentation for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Gitlab supports review system, we are using it right now in our project. No extra steps are necessary

Comment: Can you please provide me the steps on how to use the review in gitlab?